# How to make installable package for Django project for Windows machine?

Tags: python, django, angular, windows, django-rest-framework

What is the easiest way to make a Django+DRF +Angular files (optionally) package so it can be installed on the Windows machinge? Currently we look at these options:  
1) Write `setup.py` - but it does not create virtual environment and does not deal with Angular files
2) Build `.exe` file, using libraries like `py2exe` or `pyinstaller` - but they currently throw a lot of strange errors and should be build exactly for specified architecture.
3) Build separate `.exe` for Angular and somehow write install scripts for python - may be in some `.bat` files or something else.
Will be grateful for any advices!
P.S. Currently project is developed on Linux machines.